# Removing the cookies before page load

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Whenever a site's home page is entered I want to remove it's all of the cookies. So page request parameter's( in Chrome dev tools=>Network=>Request Headers=>Cookies) should have Cookies empty.

So code in `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener` using **blocking** looks like this:

```
if (["https://www.irctc.co.in/eticketing/loginHome.jsf", "https://www.irctc.co.in"].indexOf(details.url) > -1)
                {                   
                    chrome.cookies.getAll({domain: "irctc.co.in"}, function (cookies) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {

                            chrome.cookies.remove({url: "https://" + cookies[i].domain + cookies[i].path, name: cookies[i].name}, function (res) {
                                console.log("res=", res);
                            });
                        }
                    }
                    );
                }
```

Indeed all the cookies are being removed but I still see the same cookies being sent in the page request headers. I guess by the time `chrome.cookies.remove` is executed the request is already sent.

**Is there any way avoid sending the cookies?**

Comment: @wOxxOm yes I'm using blocking webrequest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `chrome.cookies` api is asynchronous. What you want is to use `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders` with both `blocking` and `requestHeaders`. Then you want to blank the `cookie` header. It will look something like this:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(function(details){
  for (var i = 0; i < details.requestHeaders.length; ++i) {
    if(details.requestHeaders[i].name === 'Cookie') {
      details.requestHeaders[i].value = '';
      break;
    }
  }
  return {requestHeaders: details.requestHeaders};
},
{urls: ["https://www.irctc.co.in/eticketing/loginHome.jsf", "https://www.irctc.co.in/*"]},
["blocking", "requestHeaders"]);
```

Comment: C is in capitals: `details.requestHeaders[i].name === 'Cookie'`

Comment: Starting from Chrome 72, you must add 'extraHeaders' in opt_extraInfoSpec. https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/webRequest/#life-cycle-of-requests